# Get secondary Intent via getIntent() in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an application with a main activity.
From the main activity the user can go to a next with an `Intent`:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondaryActivity.class);
startActivity(AchievementInfoIntent);
```

While in the SecondaryActivity the user has the option to make a 'Tweet' in Twitter.
After successful authentication I obtain an oauth_token and oauth_verifier.

Here is what the LogCat shows:

```
05-04 15:45:05.754: INFO/ActivityManager(1274): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE] dat=callback://twitter?oauth_token=uo1yJCSkHwdbmyYp4KgUCLXYWQYFrp9sV7Me0TGyfU&oauth_verifier=fgugbGfJL3E5Gz7tfK97ukGsXfX6UoqWRMzMiJUZk cmp=my.app/.SecondaryActivity }
```

Before posting the Tweet I need to get those tokens and verifiers, so in my `onResume` function I put the following code:

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Uri uri = this.getIntent().getData();
...
```

But this returns the original `Intent` that created the SecondaryActivity, `LogCat`:

```
05-04 15:45:05.754: INFO/ActivityManager(1274): Intent { cmp=my.app/.SecondaryActivity (has extras) }
```

How can I get the Intent that returned me back to my App, and obtain all the things I need?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to get some result from SecondaryActivity to your MainActivity. You should use startActivityForResult(intent intent) for this purpose. Here is a [tutorial](http://www.mubasheralam.com/tutorials/android/how-start-new-activity-and-getting-results)

Comment: It's not like starting another activity (forResult) because I will receive a dynamic callback I have to use...